# Linked List display the data in a type of data

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to display the lists of genre in the genre type that I have in the linked list. I did:

```
public void outputGenre(){
    booksAvilable = new LinkedList <Book>();
    booksAvailable.add(new book("Enders Game",1999,new Genre ("SciFi"),3));
    booksAvailable.add(new book("Star Trek",1974,new Genre ("SciFi"),4));
    booksAvailable.add(new book("Game of Thrones",1991,new Genre ("Drama"),3));

    System.out.println("We have following Genres");
    for(Book books:booksAvilable()){
        Genre genre = books.getGenre();
        System.out.println(genre);
    }
}
```

This code outputs SciFi twice and Drama once. I want to make it display SciFi only once. I thought of using counter and `if`/`else` statements, but I got lost.

Comment: pls show the Genre class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you asked for a version *without* streams, though I cannot imagine why:

```
Set<Genre> seen = new HashSet<>();
for(Book books:booksAvailable() ){

   Genre genre = books.getGenre();

   if (!seen.contains(genre)) {
       System.out.println(genre);
       seen.add(genre);
   }
}
```

In this case you need to maintain a record of which genres you already have seen and only display it if not yet seen.

It doesn't take much arguing that the streaming variant is cleaner and more concise.

Still requires an implementation of `equals` to function correctly, and because I used a `HashSet` also a `int hashCode()`, which simply can return the hashcode of the genre's name string.

Yet another form is recording the names of the genres in a set, requiring two loops:

```
Set<String> genres = new HashSet<>();
for(Book books:booksAvailable() ){
   Genre genre = books.getGenre();
   genres.add(genre.getName());
}

 for(String genre : genres) {
       System.out.println(genre);
 }
```

I'd still go for the stream solution, personally.

Comment: Because i am learning OOP and Linked list specially and Streams are too complex for me now. Still got more to learn to get there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java streams:

```
 booksAvailable.stream().map(Book::getGenre).distinct().forEach(System.out::println)
```

Assuming you have an `equals` method in your `Genre` class, otherwise it can't determine the distinct cases of a genre.

Comment: is there a way without using Streams

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik because there is two lists with same Genre Sci fi.